# How do I import values to already existing excel file w/o overwriting original content with Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm really new in coding at all, I'm trying to automate one activity.. So I need to create xlsx file like "Example1", that is work for me, and now I have to import to this new created xlsx data which I need from other excel file, but I need imported data to be starting on specific column and row. "Example2" also work for me, but not together with Example1, could anyone help me please ?

```
#Example1
        import xlsxwriter
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample1.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'SampleText')    
    worksheet.write(1, 0, 'SampleText') 
    worksheet.write(2, 0, 'SampleText') 
    worksheet.write(3, 0, 'SampleText')    
    
    workbook.close()
```

Example2

```
#Example2
import pandas as pd

Excelsample = 'data.xlsx'
Sampleoutput = 'output.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(Excelsample, sheet_name="Sheet1",usecols="A,H:AD")
data.to_excel(Sampleoutput, sheet_name='Sheet1',startcol=2,startrow=13, index=False)
```

Comment: I don't think you can merge with to_excel nor with data.ExcelWriter.  The technique I have used involves ```data = data.append(pd.read_excel(Sampleoutput), ignore_index=True)```

Then to data.to_excel on the appended dataframe.  You have to manage where things are but you won't overwrite data.  If the same cell in the two excel files is occupied, append shifts the over and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

Excelsample = 'data.xlsx'
Sampleoutput = 'output.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(Excelsample, sheet_name="Sheet1")
data = data.append(pd.read_excel(Sampleoutput, sheet_name="Sheet1"), ignore_index=True)

data.to_excel(Sampleoutput, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```